# Molarity of a mix between solid and solution

Tags: aqueous-solution, concentration, stoichiometry

$\pu{50 g}$ of solid $\ce{NaOH}$ is added to $\pu{1.5 L}$ of $\pu{2.4 M}$ $\ce{NaOH}.$ Water is then added to the mix until the solution reaches $\pu{5 L}.$ I need to find molarity of the final solution.

I am a bit confused because I have different answers with my friends, my approach was as follows.

The molarity $x$ when I add solid $\ce{NaOH}$ to $\pu{1.5 L}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ assuming $n_1 = n_2:$

$$x = \frac{\pu{1.5 g} \cdot \pu{2.4 M}}{\pu{1.55 g}} = \pu{2.322 M}$$

The molarity $y$ after I add more water also assuming $n_1 = n_2:$

$$y = \frac{\pu{1.55 g} \cdot \pu{2.322 M}}{5} = \pu{0.72 M}$$

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Always try to approach the task first by general algebraic solution and plug in the numbers in the end.  It has several benefits. 
1/ It allows you better grasp on underlying principles. 
2/ It allows both of you  and readers to more easily spot a solution error or conceptual mistake. 
3/ It gives to the Q/A a higher and more permanent value to be reused/applied for similar questions. 
4/ It follows the site policy to focus on explaining principles and procedures, rather than solving of particular tasks with the value for 1 person only. 
5/ You will avoid the intermediate rounding errors.

Comment: Additionally, always use units in expressions with literal numbers like above.

Comment: is it still wrong sir?

Comment: Try to plug in the numbers AFTER you get the final algebraic expression that provides the result. For formatting of chem/math formulas/expressions, use can use [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here),

Comment: Why not to use e.g. $$c = \frac {n}{V_2} = \frac {\frac{m}{M} + c_1 \cdot V_1}{V_2}$$

Comment: How moles of NaOH do you have in total? Your final volume is 5L so divide (moles of NaOH) by 5 to get the molarity.

Comment: @Poutnik - You edited the question and added units to the OP's mathematical expression $1.5*2.4/1.55$. For the 1.5*2.4 part I think the OP was trying to get the moles of NaOH in the solution. I think the 1.55 in the denominator came from assuming that the solid NaOH had a density of 1 and adding the volume of the NaOH solution to get that the final volume of the solution after adding the solid NaOH was 1.55 Liters.

Comment: @MaxW AFAIK, I have not added units, intentionally, aside of changing gr  to g, unless accidentally. OP had added them after my early comments, before I applied the formatting.

Comment: @Poutnik - Sorry, you're correct. The OP added the nonsensical units in the first edit of the  post. Your very positive contributions to the site should have given me pause before I made such a stupid accusation.

Comment: @MaxW Your appreciation is very welcome. :-)

Comment: I am sorry to not make a correct format for asking questions, I have already found my mistake. Thank you for the advise sir @Poutnik, I'll write better questions then. Thank you too sir MaxW for the formula.